# 'be ing' vs 'be supposed to' in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given that, a listener and a speaker are talking on the road, if the speaker says

> "I am swimming in the gym",

1. **What does it mean?** .I guess it's like a plan though.
2. **If it is like a plan, how is it different from this?** : I am supposed to go swimming in the gym.

Comment: **Supposed to** expresses (among other things) obligation or requirement. "I am supposed to be studying now for the final exam, but let's go get a cup of coffee instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Be+ing** can sometimes be used to convey the immediate **future**. For example, you can very well say:

> Tomorrow, I'm going to the mall.

But in your context, just saying *I am swimming in the gym* means that he is actually swimming in the gym right now (in which case the poor fellow might have bigger problems than grammar).

An acceptable way to say what you want to say would be:

> **Tomorrow** *(or any other date that is relatively close to today),* **I'm going swimming at the gym**.

Comment: +1, but also we sometimes use **be +ing** to indicate a general condition or ongoing action, like "I'm working at Foomatic Corporation" even if you're not literally working there at the very moment you say that.

Comment: +1. "These days I'm swimming in the new gym, but later today I'm swimming in the old gym because the pool in the new gym has been too crowded."

Comment: What are you doing these days?  I'm swimming in the gym.

Comment: "That's it. I'm suing." -- The speaker doesn't have to be in the court while in the process of their "suing", I believe.